# no trackball click with ICS/JB Android emulator

Tags: android, emulation, trackball

I have a problem, with **ICS** and **JB** emulators
(but **NOT** with emulators with *older version of Android*, for example `API 10 = Android 2.3.3`.) :

I do not manage to click when in trackball mode **([F6] or [del])**, even in home screens.

In `onTrackballEvent(MotionEvent event)`, `ACTION_MOVE` events are triggered, but not

`ACTION_DOWN` nor `ACTION_UP`.

Is there a (known ?) bug with **ICS** and **JB** emulators ? Is there something I do the wrong way ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried this on a real device?